# Python : Subtracting inside an array

Tags: python, arrays, subtraction

I'm trying to subtract the values in an array with 10 values that the user inputs. So far I can't find how to do that. This is what I have...

```
g = 0
q = []

for s in range(9):    
    while g < 10:
        n = input()
        q.append(int(n))
        g = g+1

add = sum(Q)

sub =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more succinct ways to do this; I've opted instead for readability:

```
# get our initial input:
n = input()
result = int(n)

# subtract the rest of the user's inputs:
for x in range(9):
    n = input()
    result -= int(n)

# ... do something with the result ...
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is subtract all of the values from each other. For example, 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0

Comment: If I wanted to multiply or divide, what would I need to change? My guess would be changing the -= to something like *=  ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what you would do with the code I provided. You could also initialize result to 1, delete the initial input and instead iterate to 10, which would simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign all of those to individual variables. At each iteration of the loop, you could just append the newly input value to the array:

```
q = []
g = 0
while g < 10:
    n = input()
    q.append(int(n))
    g = g + 1
```

At the end of this loop, `q` will contain the 10 values that the user entered.

It's not clear to me what needs to be subtracted from what, but that might get you a little closer to where you need to be.

Comment: Or `for _ in xrange(10):`, then they don't have to even worry about `g`.

Comment: Yes, quite. I figured that in this case it's probably best to pick our battles.

Comment: Ah thank you that makes it a lot cleaner. Sorry I'm just starting programming and trying to do an assignment for class. I need to subtract all the numbers that are put into the array. I did sum to add all of them and I don't know how to subtract/multiply/divide them.

Comment: Right.  Especially since this is for a class, the OP may have been told they have to use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Be pythonic

`a = [int(input()) for x in range(10)]`

Or for python 2.X

`a = [int(raw_input()) for x in xrange(10)]`

This gives you a list containing 10 integers.

Then you can
`q = map(lambda x: x-sum(a), q)`,
which subtracts the sum of user inputs

Comment: i am a beginner in Python.... i don't exactly understand this q = map(lambda... can you explain it a little.. ?

Comment: See this. http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map

Answer (score 0):

Just use python API

```
li = []
for x in xrage(10):
    li.append(input())
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x - y, li)
```